# This runs on single thread or multi thread?

Tags: java, java-8, thread-safety

Whether this program runs on **single thread** or **multi thread**??

**Servlet**

```
public class PagesNavigation extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public UserData user = null;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);

        try {
            user = new UserData();  //I will use this object to access all functions.

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**class: UserData**

```
 public class UserData {

    AvailableProducts availableProducts = new AvailableProducts();
    UserSelectedProduct userSelectedProduct = new UserSelectedProduct();
    ProductsCart productsCart = new ProductsCart();
    CartView cartView = new CartView();
    ProductsForCheckout productsForCheckout = new ProductsForCheckout();
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should have a look at [how do servlets work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-sessions-shared-variables-and-multithreadi).

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify - servlets are singletons, and they are definitely run by multiple threads.

Also, AvailableProducts could possibly also be a singleton and shared among all users - unless you custom tailor the products for a given user.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing Java Enterprise Edition programming (which `HttpServlet` normally is), then it's all multi-threaded, with a very few specific exceptions.  Your `UserData` object will almost certainly need to be thread safe.